# How to stop execution of the custom activity until ListItemChanged event occurs on the sharepoint site (list)

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, android-activity, sharepoint-workflow, custom-activity

I'm building a custom Sharepoint 2010 activity which does some business logic, and at the end of that process, it writes down a list item with some data. I need that activity to hold execution of the workflow until the list item changes (let's say until that data is reviewed and approved). Polling the list is unacceptable, so i tried the following solution...

[image: Custom activity design]

So the logic is that after activity's Execute method is executed, whileActivity1 keep the execution looping until handleExternalEventActivity1 event handler see that listItem Status column is changed to "approved". If status is not "approved", event handler should hold the execution until next event occurs...

With this design, I really can see that execution stops the first time, but when I change the Status value in the listItem, nothing happens.

Anyone can help me with this? I you have better solution for the design itself, that's acceptable too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179762/how-to-trigger-a-sharepoint-workflow-by-updating-only-a-value-in-a-list-item-ap) answer fit your needs. In any case, try to avoid using delay activities/while loop (it's not real time).